# About the $1$ of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I could not find neither a proof nor a counterexample, can anyone solve this?

> Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra. (It not necessarily has $1$.)
>   If $$\mu:A\otimes A \rightarrow A,\ x\otimes y \mapsto xy$$ is surjective, does $A$ have $1$?

Comment: not sure why someone has downvoted this question. It doesn't look trivial to me.

Comment: My guess is the answer is yes, with a proof similar to that given in [this problem](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181794/finite-dimensional-simple-nonunital-associative-algebras) - adjoin a unit, and use Artin-Wedderburn to obtain a system of idempotents modulo nilpotents. My guess is you'll be able to extract an idempotent for $A$ somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  A counter-example would be the sub-algebra of the algebra of $3\times 3$ matrices described by
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} k & k & k \\ 0 & 0 & k \\ 0 & 0 & k \end{pmatrix}. $$
For this algebra, $\mu:A\otimes A\to A$ is surjective, but there cannot be an identity element, since there are no $X\in A$ such that 
$$ X\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$